# WSO2 ESB digest value

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I receive a request with a password that I have to check. This password is a field in the body section. I have to check it against and digested password (such us MD5, but some other algorithms are welcome).

Is there any kind of mediator or internal function to help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [Class Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Class+Mediator). This is also a mediator where you can specify the mediation logic in a java class and attach to a sequence. [This sample](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Sample380) shows how to get values in the message context, edit them and set back the altered values to the message context.

Likewise you can get the password form the message body, alter/check the password, and set in the message body. Digest calculation can be done inside the class mediator. Sample java code to calculate digest can be found [here](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/security/digest.xtp).

Comment: Thanks CharithaM. I finally did it by an md5 javascript algorithm, using an script mediator.